# How to change the text of a label after pressing the button which are in Custom UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have an UITableView,where i"m getting a customUITableViewCell with an UILabel and an UIButton,i want to change the Label text value for particular row after pressing the button which in same row. Please help me,i'm new in iPhone.

Answer (score 3):

Please check whether you mapped action fro your button and continue with this..

```
-(void)yourButtonClicked:(id)sender {
  CustomCell *clickedCell = [[sender superView]superView];
  NSindexPath *indexPath = [YourTableViewObject indexPathForCell:clickedCell];
  NSLog(@"%d %d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row);  
}
```

Here you are getting row for your clicked cell..

Then you can change your label text easily.. by

```
clickedCell.yourLabel.text = @"Your string";
```